# Type Creation and Execution

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have created a type to print experience of employees from employees table for 5 employees with one incorrect id. I have created an exception to skip it but I am not getting the result for it. What mistake have I done? Please refer my query and tell the error.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE emp_id_typ IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE emp_exp_typ IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE exp_sp ( p_empid   IN  emp_id_typ
                                   , p_exp     OUT emp_exp_typ)
IS
v_exp   NUMBER;
BEGIN
    FOR i IN p_empid.FIRST..p_empid.COUNT
    LOOP
    p_exp.EXTEND;
    SELECT ROUND(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, hire_date)/12) INTO v_exp FROM employees
     WHERE employee_id = p_empid(i);
    p_exp(p_exp.LAST) := v_exp;
    END LOOP;
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        v_exp := NVL(v_exp, 'NULL');
END exp_sp;
/

DECLARE
    v_empid emp_id_typ := emp_id_typ( );
    v_exp   emp_exp_typ := emp_exp_typ( );
BEGIN
    v_empid := emp_id_typ(101, 102, 52, 100, 206);
    FOR i IN v_empid.FIRST..v_empid.COUNT
    LOOP
    exp_sp(v_empid(i), v_exp(i));
    dbms_output.put_line(v_empid(i), v_exp(i));
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Not quite sure what you're seeing. Is your client configured to see the `dbms_output` buffer? e.g. in SQL\*Plus or SQL Developer, `set serveroutput on`, or enabling it for the connection in your IDE? Or is your `when others` handler just supposed to be assigning a value to `p_exp` instead of `v_exp`? You can't assign the string `'NULL'` to a `number` collection though...

Comment: No i am just practicing

Comment: "I am not getting the result" implies it runs but doesn't give the result you expect, whereas actually you get errors from the anonymous block. It's really much more helpful if you include what you expect and what you actually see in your question.

Answer (score 2):

You have several errors in both the procedure and the anonymous block. In the procedure:

- You haven't initialised the OUT `p_exp` collection. As it's an OUT parameter you have to do it inside the procedure. (Alternatively make it IN OUT).
- Your exception handler terminates the loop, so the `v_exp` you set in there is never used, and the `p_exp` collection is incomplete. (It's also bad practise to use `when others`.)
- You can't assign a string like ``NULL'` to a number variable or collection. Either assign an a magic number that represents an error to the caller, or leave it null.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE exp_sp ( p_empid   IN  emp_id_typ
                                   , p_exp     OUT emp_exp_typ)
IS
  v_exp   NUMBER;
BEGIN
  -- have to initialise p_exp
  p_exp := emp_exp_typ();
  -- better to use either 1..count, or first..last; don't mix them
  --FOR i IN p_empid.FIRST..p_empid.COUNT
  FOR i IN p_empid.FIRST..p_empid.LAST
  LOOP
    p_exp.EXTEND;
    -- you want the exception handler to deal with this row then continue,
    -- so use a nested block
    BEGIN
      SELECT ROUND(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, hire_date)/12) INTO v_exp FROM employees
      WHERE employee_id = p_empid(i);
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
        -- you can't assign a string to a number
        --v_exp := NVL(v_exp, 'NULL');
        -- just an example as not clear what you need
        v_exp := -1;
    END; -- nested block with exception handler
    p_exp(p_exp.LAST) := v_exp;
  END LOOP;
END exp_sp;
/
```

And in your anonymous block:

- The initialisation of `v_exp` is redundant as the procedure argument is OUT. Not an error but pointless.
- You are calling the procedure inside the loop, passing a single element; it should be called once outside the loop and passed the whole collection(s).
- Your call to `dbms_output.put_line` is wrong; that only takes a single argument, so you have to build a string up e.g. with concatenation.

```
DECLARE
  v_empid emp_id_typ := emp_id_typ( );
  -- assignment is redundant
  -- v_exp   emp_exp_typ := emp_exp_typ( );
  v_exp   emp_exp_typ;
BEGIN
  v_empid := emp_id_typ(101, 102, 52, 100, 206);
  -- moved this call up, without indexing
  exp_sp(v_empid, v_exp);
  -- better to use either 1..count, or first..last; don't mix them
  -- FOR i IN v_empid.FIRST..v_empid.COUNT
  FOR i IN v_empid.FIRST..v_empid.LAST
  LOOP
    --exp_sp(v_empid(i), v_exp(i));
    -- fixed call to dbms_output
    dbms_output.put_line(v_empid(i) ||': '|| v_exp(i));
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

which gets:

```
101: 28
102: 25
52: -1
100: 30
206: 24


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

---

> I need not to print the third variable as it is not in the table.

You can test the `v_exp` value for the magic number (or null, which is safer, but the procedure needs to be modified slightly for that), and only print the results which  you need:

```
...
  FOR i IN v_empid.FIRST..v_empid.LAST
  LOOP
    IF v_exp(i) != -1 THEN
      dbms_output.put_line(v_empid(i) ||': '|| v_exp(i));
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
...
```

which gets:

```
101: 28
102: 25
100: 30
206: 24

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: I need not to print the third variable as it is not in the table. On comin to third variable it must print the next variable.

Comment: OK, so  check the `v_exp` value and `continue` the loop if it's -1 (or null if you use that instead of a magic number).